# How do I get the application to display in the current session

Tags: arch-linux, x11, vnc

- I installed `tigervnc` on my `arch` and connected it with an `Android phone`. At this time, I have two `X sessions` on my machine: a local display `session` and a `session` connected with an `Android phone`
- But when I run the `X app` on my local machine, it shows up on my android phone
- I know that `gvim` can use the following syntax to specify where to `display`, then what should other applications do

```
gvim -display :1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some applications have `-display` switch, but not all. For other applications you can set the `$DISPLAY` variable like this

```
DISPLAY=:1 <your app>
DISPLAY=:0 <your other app>
```

In this way, each will open on the screen defined in `DISPLAY`. I do it like this all the time. If you want all applications to open on a particular screen you can set `$DISPLAY` globally. For instance:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

Then you just run the application and it will open on exported `$DISPLAY`.

Comment: I found that if I first open chromium in session a , and then I open chromium in session B , it will still show up in session A . There are many applications that can not be opened more , how do you solve this problem ?

Comment: Chromium and other browsers have a bit different way of opening new windows. Have you tried with `--new-window` option? What do you mean with "other applications cannot be opened more". Do they allow only one instance?

Comment: yes，they just allow only one instance，For example , rofi , when I open it in one session , I cannot open it in another session . And my polybar doesn ' t work properly when VNC is connected . Although they say VNC is better than RDP , I think windows remote desktop is more suitable for me , do you know how to make VNC load session from local macine?

Comment: You have to know what you want from your setup and what is possible. I looked up what rofi and polybar are. They are typical apps for one session, and they will never work as you expect from them in your setup. You would need Xinerama or something similar to be able to use these apps over more displays, but again, I don't think Xeinrama will work for your setup. I guess you have noticed that you cannot move a window from display :0 to :1 and vice versa. Therefore rofi and polybar are also limited to one display only. Maybe it would work if you used different user accounts on each display.

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you for your help